# Remove all JMenuItem from JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I got the JMenu down except for removing. :D I mean, I can do `popup.remove(NUMBER)` but that can cause NPE errors. So, is there a way to remove all `JMenuItems` from `JMenu`?

Here's my update `checkPopup()` if anyone's interested:

```
            private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger())
        {

            int itemSelectx = listbox.getSelectedIndex();
            Object actItemx = listbox.getModel().getElementAt(itemSelectx);
            System.out.println("You pressed on " + actItemx);

        if (actItemx == "Item 1") {
            popup.add(cancelMenuItem); // add the ability to cancel an item
            popup.add(dropMenuItem); // add ability to drop the item
        }

            popup.show(inv.this, e.getX(), e.getY()); // show item at mouse
            popup.revalidate(); // revalidate
            //popup.remove(0); // removing first (0) menu item
        }
    }
```

Almost there! :) (yes, I [tried Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&&sa=X&ei=1OlJTZ2TNcL48Aa1h8jtDg&ved=0CBIQBSgA&q=JListMenu+remove+all+Menu+Items&spell=1) and JavaDocs)

Comment: the reason your google search didn't work was because you looked for JListMenu instead of JMenu :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I've understood what you're after correctly, you want the `removeAll()` method on `JMenu`; See the Javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#removeAll%28%29).